# use ng build --prod didn't created a dist folder

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, server

I'm developing an ionic app and I use `ng build --prod` but d't generate a dist folder. I run it in root folder of the project. No errors in the console, all good, and also no dist folder was generated in the root folder location.
Below is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not a file which is used by angular compiler please paste here the angular.json

Comment: user simple ng build

Comment: If this is an ionic application, run `ionic build`. Then, look in the www folder in the project for the build artifacts.

Comment: cool,I use ionic build and found the index.html in the www folder, thanks so much!!

Comment: and there are soooo many files files in my www folder, is the role of www folder in ionic app same as the role of dist folder in angular app?